# Load different assembly or module for different client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have developed a web application in .net 4.5, now a customer ask me a customization for some module of application (for example a different implementation of invoices) .
My question is can i "intercept" my customer for load customized assembly and load different assembly for general customer?

can i do it simply by reflection?

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to design the software the way its parts can be easily replaced. You should have separated your solution into multiple projects, so that you can quickly swap different implementations of your interfaces.

Furthermore, there's a thing called Dependency Injection, which basically means you can inject a different implementation depending on your needs either during a runtime or using a config file for instance. For the ease of use there are nice frameworks already prepared for you, like Ninject or Unity.

The application needs to have a solid architecture to support such possibilities. Maybe if you've provided more information about your system, I could have been more specific, but I believe doing some research on dependency injection will give you a good start.

Comment: i just have a separate solutions and use ninject. My question is can i load versioning assembly of "module" without reinstall a separate application for my customer if application is a SaaS?

Comment: If you're already using ninject and you've chosen the path to define mappings in an external file and not in the code, then I believe it's possible. Simply copy the new dll into the application folder and modify the ninject settings file containing the mappings. Give it a try :) However, if you can't control it like this, then I think it won't be as easy, you'd have to modify core files to make it possible. There are probably (not sure really) some ways of intercepting calls and stuff, but I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can load an assembly from file, like this
`var asmbly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(path);`
And then use Reflection to load types.

There are several ways you can achieve this pluggability. One way is to extract the interface of the "module" and code your "module client" agains that interface, decoupling the concrete implementation from your "client" code. Then, at run time look inside the assempbly, load the type that implements said interface and inject into "module client".

I am pasting here some code I've written as a proof of concept for exacly that type of run-time loading of "modules" (this is MVC 3):

```
// "Module User" was decoupled from "module", by coding it against module's interface:
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    // dependency injection constructor
    public CustomerController(
            ...
            ICustomerRepository customerRepository,
            ...)
    {
            _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }


    public ActionResult Details(Nullable<Guid> id)
    {
            Customer c = _customerRepository.GetByKey(id.Value.ToString());
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

At run time:

```
// I first load the assembly
System.Reflection.Assembly dal = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(pBinPath, pDALAssemblyName));

// I then look for types implementing ICustomerRepository 
var addressRepositoryContract = typeof(QSysCamperCore.Domain.IAddressRepository);
var addressRepositoryImplementation = dal.GetTypes()
    .First(p => addressRepositoryContract.IsAssignableFrom(p));
...
```

Note, that this type of programming requires a little more permissions - I am already a few years "rusty" on this code, but I remember issues with the trust level and, of course, file system access has to be considered.

---

There are frameworks that aid such application style. This is again a few years old, but there used to be so-called "Composite Application Block" on Microsoft's Patterns and Practices site, which was the base of two frameworks - Smart Cliet Softweare Factory and its web equivavelnt - Web Client Software Factory. They were a little heavier to stand up, but provided gread skeleton for such modularized (composite) applications.